# How to use the Android Apache HttpDelete class with parameter

Tags: java, android

I need to send an ID to the server and have the server to delete one record in a DB.
I want to use the HttpDelete Apache Android SDK integrated class but I cannot figure out how to use it and how to pass parameters to the server.
With the POST request I use .setEntity method on the HttpPost class.
But in HttpDelete there's no .setEntity method.

What I have so far achieved is:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpDelete httpdelete = new HttpDelete(url);
 httpdelete.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");
 response = httpclient.execute(httpdelete);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP DELETE requests do not have a body.  You pass parameters right on the URL:

```
 String url = "http://foo.com/bar?bing=bang"
 HttpDelete httpdelete = new HttpDelete(url);
```

Comment: So should I treat it like a GET method ?

Comment: Yes, treat it like a GET method in that you are putting your data on the URL.  However presumably you have chosen the DELETE verb over GET for a good reason.  If this is a REST service, DELETE is used to delete a resource from the server.  GET is used to read the resource.